# Changing cocoapod compile platform

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api

On xcode, I'm trying to use a pod to implement a mail API in Swift. When I try to build the framework, I get this error:

> Compiling for iOS 8.0, but module 'Alamofire' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 10.0

How do I change the pod so it builds for iOS 10.0 or above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs due to the Alamofire has updated its library. While Evreflection has not updated for the Alamofires updated version. You need to specify the Version of Alamofire here.
Use this line in podfile to specify the version

```
  pod 'EVReflection/Alamofire','~> 5.10.1'
  pod 'Alamofire','~> 4.9.1'
```

Then deintegrate the pods from project and install it again.
This would solve the problem you are facing

Answer (score -2):

You should up `Deployment Target` of your app to 10.0 in your project's settings because you can't use pods with highest iOS version than you use in the project.:[image: XCode Deployment Target]

Comment: This will lead to making many changes to the pods. Which is least preferable.